# Is there a way of scraping a list of HTML elements based on key words where the document structure is indeterminate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xpath, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am building a scraper to be used on many sites (too many to scrape manually using a web scraping tool such as Octoparse).

Each site will probably be different in structure. Some sites may have data that I wish to be scraped; some may not.  This is to be determined using a list of keywords/keyphrases. Of sites that I wish data to be parsed, these are likely to be presented in a list of some way.  However, the HTML elements used to present the list is indeterminate (i.e. could be a ul list, li list, a div list, a table, etc).

If a keyword/keyphrase is found, I wish for not only that element to be parsed, but all others that may be part of the same list/group.

Example 1

```
<div>
  <h1>Random content I am not interested in</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Some more random content I am not interested in</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Dogs</li>
    <li>Cats</li>
    <li>Birds</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Example 2

```
<div>
  <h1>Random content I am not interested in</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Some more random content I am not interested in</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>Bob</h1>
        <p>A description of Bob</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1>Ben</h1>
        <p>A description of Ben</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1>Bill</h1>
        <p>A description of Bill</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

From example one, if I had identified the element `Dogs`, I would like the result to be `Dogs, Cats, Birds`.

From example two, if I had identified Ben, I would like the result to be 3 div elements, each of which contains the heading and paragraph; the key is that all results are to include HTML, not just text.

Any help/guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your description of the desired output is somewhat confusing; can you provide the actual outputs for these two examples?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for some kind of custom NLP solution

Answer (score 0):

I managed something like this:

```
static IEnumerable<string> FindSimilarItems(string html, string[] values, int maxDepth)
{
    var doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);
    var output = new List<string>();

    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        var rootElement = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode($"//*[text()='{value}']");
        if (rootElement == null) continue;
        for (int i = 0; i < maxDepth; i++)
        {
            var newXpath = RemoveXpathGroupIndex(rootElement.XPath, i);
            var newElements = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(newXpath);
            if (newElements.Count <= 1) continue;

            output.AddRange(newElements.Select(x => x.InnerText));
        }
    }

    return output.GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
}

static string RemoveXpathGroupIndex(string xpath, int groupElement)
{
    var splited = xpath.Split('/');
    var pickedElement = splited.Length - 1 - groupElement;
    splited[pickedElement] = splited[pickedElement].Substring(0, splited[pickedElement].IndexOf('['));
    return string.Join("/", splited);
}
```

This code:

```
var similarItems = FindSimilarItems(input1, new string[] { "Dogs" }, 3);
```

Will return

```
["Dogs", "Cats", "Birds"]
```